# Classes for different tooltips size

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm modifying the Bootstrap 3 Tooltips by creating additional classes in my CSS to complement them by combining classes.

I've already created support for colored tooltips, following the base styles (success, danger, warning, info and primary), but now I can't do the same for sizes.

Using the Firefox Inspector, after learn how to avoid the created element to disappear (*nasty*), I've got the HTML rendered:

```
<span data-original-title="File already exists" title="" class="glyphicon tooltip-danger glyphicon-remove tooltip-lg"></span>
<div style="top: 42.5px; left: 70px; display: block;" id="tooltip821719" class="tooltip fade top in" role="tooltip">
    <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
    <div class="tooltip-inner">
        File already exists
    </div>
</div>
```

The **<span>** is created, in the JavaScript, by:

```
var icon = $( '<span/>' ).addClass( 'glyphicon' ).data( 'toggle', 'tooltip' );

    icon.addClass( 'tooltip-danger' )
        .addClass( 'glyphicon-remove' )
        .addClass( 'tooltip-lg' )
        .prop( 'title', file.error )
        .tooltip();
```

The class **tooltip-danger** is one of the coloring classes I manetioned. Here it's responsible to make the tooltip *red-ish* (background and border only).

My goal is the **tooltip-lg** which, theoretically, should allow me to control the size.

I'm not an expert in CSS but I thought this definition:

```
.tooltip-lg .tooltip-inner {
  /** styles from btn-lg */
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Would be enough to style but it didn't work as expected. I know it's possible, but I don't know how.

Comment: I would suggest you to add the `.tooltip-lg` class next to the `.tooltip` class instead of replacing it, just like it happens for buttons where you add both e.g. `.btn` and `.btn-warning`. In Chrome's DevTools your code seems to work.

Comment: I would like to do this without use the Tooltip API, which afaik would be the way to do it by changing the **template** option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a matter of analyze the resulting HTML a little more.

I was using the **within** selector, but the element with **.tooltip-inner** class wasn't *inside* the element with **.tooltip-lg**. It was inside *another* element sibling the one I've defined (**.tooltip**).

So instead of using:

```
.tooltip-lg .tooltip-inner {}
```

I used:

```
.tooltip-lg + .tooltip .tooltip-inner {}
```

And it worked. :D

I've created now five classes with five different sizes which I think are very proportional to their names. I'll leave them here in case anyone need something like that too:

```
.tooltip-x-sm + .tooltip .tooltip-inner, .tooltip-sm + .tooltip .tooltip-inner, .tooltip-md + .tooltip .tooltip-inner,
.tooltip-lg   + .tooltip .tooltip-inner, .tooltip-x-lg + .tooltip .tooltip-inner {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33;
}

.tooltip-x-sm + .tooltip .tooltip-inner {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
}

.tooltip-sm + .tooltip .tooltip-inner {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.tooltip-md + .tooltip .tooltip-inner {
  padding: 7px 14px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 350px;
  max-width: 350px;
}

.tooltip-lg + .tooltip .tooltip-inner {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.tooltip-x-lg + .tooltip .tooltip-inner {
  padding: 9px 18px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 640px;
  max-width: 640px;
}
```